# How to capture domain name and record In Google Universal Analytics via Tag Manager

Tags: tags, cross-domain, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, domain-name

I am implementing Google Tag Manager. We are using Universal Analytics. We manage close to 100 sites and apps.

I wish to compress and consolidate our analytics into a single tracking code and profile. But in order to do this I need analytics to capture and record the domain name.

How do I set a GTM tag to capture the domain name in Universal Analytics.

I've Googled this and saw some Google help on cross browser capture and `allowLinker`, etc. but I am not sure that is the way to achieve what I am after.

Thanks.

**Question Clarified**

For purposes of an example, consider this as part of our portfolio (*all sites use same GA Tracking Code and GTM Container ID*):

- Site 1 (of approx. 100) = abc.com | UA-98765432-1 | GTM-A1B2C3
- Site 2 (of approx. 100) = xyz.com | UA-98765432-1 | GTM-A1B2C3

So when I go to our (Google) Universal Analytics dashboard and profile reports for UA-98765432-1 I would like to see all report data contain its corresponding domain name -- abc.com and/or xzy.com

To me, on the surface, it seems like that is an easy thing to capture and see.

Comment: The domain name (`Hostname` in GA) is already captured by default. You just need to add that in as a secondary dimension in, for example, the All Pages report. `allowLinker` is for configuring cross-domain tracking. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: Thanks @nyuen. I clarified my OQ.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You just need to add a filter in GA to append the hostname. You can do that with an Advanced Filter to append `Hostname` to the `Request URI`.

Comment: Ok, thanks @nyuen. I went to Account > Property > View > Filters. I clicked Add Filter. I clicked Custom (Filter Type) and selected the Advanced radio button. In the Field A -> Extract A area I selected Hostname in the dropdown. Do I type Request URI in the box next to it?

Comment: Yeah, so Hostname is `(.*)` and Request URI is also `(.*)` and then the output is `$A1$B1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a filter to prepend the hostname to all your hits:

[image]

The result becomes `http://www.hostname.com/request_uri`.

Comment: Perfect @nyuen. Just what I was looking for.